# WinSCP using PowerShell is adding a directory to the SFTP site I'm uploading to

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using a PowerShell script and WinSCP to upload a file onto an SFTP site, `Root\Users\SFTPSite` and it's placing the directory onto the SFTP site that I'm uploading from. So instead of putting it on `Root\Users\SFTPSite` it's putting it into `Root\Users\SFTPSite\Outbound`.  Not sure if it's a permissions issue that's preventing me from placing it in the `SFTPSite` directory or something to do with how the SFTP site was setup or something else because I'm using the same script for other sites without a problem. Here are the parameters I'm using

```
param (
    $localPath = "\\fileshare\ftp\ThirdParty\Outbound\",
    $remotePath = "/users/SFTPSite/"
)
```

And here is how I'm transferring,

```
$transferResult = $session.PutFiles($localPath, $remotePath, $False, $transferOptions)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. - Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it because you are copying the directory ?

Do you try to copy the content adding a `*` ?

```
 param (
     $localPath = "\\fileshare\ftp\ThirdParty\Outbound\*",
     $remotePath = "/users/SFTPSite/"
      )
```